# LVM2 pvdisplay and vgdisplay disagree

Tags: linux, gentoo, lvm

In my laptop, I have a single hard drive (`/dev/sda`). On this hard drive, I have an EFI partition (`/dev/sda1`), a boot partition (`/dev/sda2`), and an encrypted partition containing `/` (`/dev/sda3`). Inside the encrypted partition is an LVM volume group, which contains a couple of logical volumes (`/`, a swap partiton, etc.).

All of this works fine; my initrd sets everything up correctly, and the system boots without any issues. However, after booting, I wanted to be able to manage the volume group. When I tried to do so, I got the following output:

```
# pvdisplay /dev/mapper/root 
  --- Physical volume --- 
  PV Name               /dev/mapper/root 
  VG Name               localdisk 
  PV Size               931.31 GiB / not usable 1.69 MiB 
  Allocatable           yes (but full) 
  PE Size               4.00 MiB 
  Total PE              238416 
  Free PE               0 
  Allocated PE          238416 
  PV UUID               I3wArE-g6yl-9ywx-Df8d-3w1N-wuuQ-FrQjoK 

# vgdisplay localdisk 
  Volume group "localdisk" not found 
  Skipping volume group localdisk
```

How is it possible that `pvdisplay` reports that the physical device is a member of the volume group `localdisk`, however `vgdisplay` insists that the very same volume group doesn't exist? What's going wrong here?

I can provide more information about my system as required / as relevant to the question. Because I am not sure what's wrong, I'm not sure what to add at this point.

These are the device mapper entries I have setup. Note the two LVM logical volumes, as well as "root" (i.e., `/dev/mapper/root`), which is the LUKS-encrypted parent partition.

```
# dmsetup info 
Name:              localdisk-swap 
State:             ACTIVE 
Read Ahead:        256 
Tables present:    LIVE 
Open count:        2 
Event number:      0 
Major, minor:      251, 1 
Number of targets: 1 
UUID: LVM-75jhqCBBFayCVQECgTH8NOFfkrjYCqiHa0oIafGLgBOZbuhrYISOHQo97Gamy74E 

Name:              localdisk-root 
State:             ACTIVE 
Read Ahead:        256 
Tables present:    LIVE 
Open count:        1 
Event number:      0 
Major, minor:      251, 2 
Number of targets: 1 
UUID: LVM-75jhqCBBFayCVQECgTH8NOFfkrjYCqiHzpANUdFbPYfliL6gmKoBdhol2zj9Gl6z 

Name:              root 
State:             ACTIVE 
Read Ahead:        256 
Tables present:    LIVE 
Open count:        2 
Event number:      0 
Major, minor:      251, 0 
Number of targets: 1 
UUID: CRYPT-LUKS1-d5f7cc568cc74201be3fde108e37162e-root
```

Here are the filesystems I have mounted (note `/dev/mapper/localdisk-root on /`):

```
# mount 
rootfs on / type rootfs (rw) 
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime) 
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=10240k,nr_inodes=1006523,mode=755) 
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,relatime,gid=5,mode=620) 
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime) 
/dev/mapper/localdisk-root on / type ext4 (rw,noatime,commit=0) 
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=805564k,mode=755) 
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime) 
shm on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime) 
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime) 
cgroup_root on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=10240k,mode=755) 
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime) 
efivarfs on /sys/firmware/efi/efivars type efivarfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime) 
openrc on /sys/fs/cgroup/openrc type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,release_agent=/lib64/rc/sh/cgroup-release-agent.sh,name=openrc) 
cpu on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu) 
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,nodev,noexec,nosuid)
```

Comment: what does `vgdisplay` (without arguments) show?

Comment: It gives me `No volume groups found`.

Comment: Weird. Do `vgs` and `vgscan` also return nothing? Also, can you post your mount output? `df -h`. Also post the output of `fdisk -l`. I'm a little puzzled by the `pvdisplay /dev/mapper/root`. In my experience the devices in `/dev/mapper` are logical volumes.

Comment: I added some more information to the OP. `vgscan` does indeed say that there are no volume groups found. `/dev/mapper/root` is the LUKS-encrypted physical volume which contains the LVM volume group - it's in `/dev/mapper` via `dm_crypt`.

Comment: You've gone beyond my (sketchy) knowledge of the subject. Is it possible that this is a bug, or expected behavior in a corner case? Have you tried asking the LVM mailing lists?

Comment: Try the command `vgs` to see what VG's you have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look in `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf`, there is a `devices { ... }` section. You probably need to adjust the filter to accept `/dev/mapper/root` as a valid location. The easiest filter would be to accept all devices: `filter = [ "a/.*/" ]`. You could also accept only the device you're interested in: `filter = [ "a|^/dev/mapper/root$|", "r/.*/" ]`.

Your initramfs probably has a different LVM configuration.

(BTW: `vgscan -vvv` is the troubleshooting tool to use here. That should show each block device it checked, and if it found anything there.)

Comment: This actually makes a lot of sense. I'll give it a go later tonight. Thanks! :)

Comment: @CmdrMoozy if it doesn't work, that `vgscan -vvv` should tell you what's going on...

Comment: This was exactly the right answer. It hadn't occurred to me, since it was being mounted by the initrd, but you're right - it needs to be initialized after booting as well, and different filters were being used. Thanks! :)

Comment: For the record, I changed my `lvm.conf` configuration to: `scan = [ "/dev", "/dev/mapper" ]` and `filter = [ "r|/dev/nbd.*|", "a|^/dev/sd|", "a|^/dev/md|", "a|^/dev/mapper/root$|" ]`, which seems to be working great.